# A strange type casting in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, casting, uikit

I found a demo snippets which used type casting like this:(int)view.'view' is a pointer of UIView's object. I have never known it can be use to cast type. Someone can help me to explain it?
paste code here

```
- (CGPoint)accelerationForView:(UIView *)view
{
    // return
    CGPoint accelecration;

    // get acceleration
    NSValue *pointValue = [self._accelerationsOfSubViews objectForKey:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)view]];
    if (pointValue == nil) {
        accelecration = CGPointZero;
    }
    else {
        [pointValue getValue:&accelecration];
    }

    return accelecration;
}

- (void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    [self._accelerationsOfSubViews removeObjectForKey:
                         [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)subview]];
}
```

Comment: Where are these demo snippets?

Comment: you have to post the code.

Comment: You need to show the actual snippet(s) here for examination. On the face of it, there's no good reason (and not even really many bad ones) for doing this.

Comment: @BenZotto: `sizeof(int)` isn't guaranteed to be equal to `sizeof(id)`, so there's that. In fact, on 64-bit Macs, it explicitly *ain't*.

Comment: They're apparently using the address of the view as a key.  Flaky, and not necessary reliable given 64-bit addresses, but technically legal.

Comment: (Casting the other way is, at best, "undefined".)

Comment: @HotLicks: Safer would be `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:(uintptr_t)theObject];` Better would be `objc_get/setAssociatedObject()` with the view as the target object.

Comment: I answered with code that adds an acceleration property to UIView. This is similar to Jonathan's suggestion.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Right, let's call that one of the bad ones then. :)

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- Well there's nothing "unsafe" about the cast, in a technical sense.  And all I said is that it's technically legal (though stupid).

Comment: @HotLicks: Not unsafe, yeah, but not *safest* either. Devil, details, etc.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan - Nothing "unsafe" -- the code will not crash, the programmer will get what the programmer asked for.  If you want "safe", code in Ada.

Comment: @HotLicks: Imagine, if you will, that an object is allocated at `0x1ABCD1234` and another at `0x2ABCD1234`. Truncation will result in both getting the same key, and thus the same object. While this probably won't cause a crash, it really depends on what the engineer is doing with the dictionary, and he/she will certainly get the wrong results.

Comment: The programmer gets precisely the results he's asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)view]
```

`view` is not an object of type `UIView`, it's a pointer of type `UIView*`. The code above casts the pointer to an int for the purpose of storing it in a `NSNumber`, apparently so that it can be used as a key in a dictionary. Since pointers themselves aren't objects, you can't use them as dictionary keys. But if you create an instance of `NSNumber` from the pointer, you can use the resulting object as a key. People do this sort of thing sometimes to keep track of some information that they want to associate with a number of objects (like views) that's not stored in the objects themselves (like acceleration).

As I mention in my comment below, the code here uses `+numberWithInteger:`, which is good because that method takes a `NSInteger`, which will be 32 bits on a 32-bit system and 64 bits on a 64-bit system. However, the author then nullified that good decision by casting to `int`, which will generally be 32 bits even on a 64-bit system. The cast should really be to `NSInteger`, like this:

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(NSInteger)view]
```

Comment: This is dangerous. Looks like the original engineer is trying to use a weak reference to an object as a key into a dictionary. The problem is that if the key object (the view) is deallocated, you'll end up with an effective memory leak. If another view is allocated at the same point in memory, then you have data associated with it that shouldn't be. Not to mention that `sizeof(id)` is not always equal to `sizeof(int)`, meaning the cast can discard important bits.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I don't know if I'd call it *dangerous* -- views don't just get deallocated by themselves. As long as the views tracked by the dictionary are managed by a single object like the containing view or a view controller, I don't think it's such a terrible thing. Agree with your second point, though -- assuming that a pointer is the same size as an `int` is a poor plan. The original author had the right idea in using `+numberWithInteger:`, since `NSInteger` more closely matches the size of a pointer, but the cast should be to `NSInteger` rather than to `int`.

Comment: If you want to use weak keys to map to objects, look at NSHashMap

Comment: Also, if you want to encapsulate an object pointer, use `+[NSValue valueWithPointer:]`

Comment: @nielsbot I'm sure you mean [NSHashTable](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html), and you're right -- that'd certainly have been a better choice. But this code may have been written before iOS 6.

Comment: Actually, I wanted `NSMapTable`. `NSHashTable` is analogous to `NSArray`, but it supports weak values. `NSMapTable` is analogous to `NSDictionary` with weak keys and/or values.

Comment: @nielsbot This is why people like Lisp. With only one data structure, there's no danger that you'll ever pick the wrong one. ;-)

Comment: @user1651560 Nope, `(NSInteger)view` is an `NSInteger` (i.e. a number); it's the call to `+[NSNumber numberWithInteger:]` that gives you a `NSNumber*`. All current iOS hardware is 32-bit, so `int` and `NSInteger` are effectively the same size. Using `NSInteger` is just a little better style -- more future-proof. Also, note nielsbot's comments -- there are better ways to do what this code is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

(NOTE: This is builds on @Caleb's answer, assuming the original code is trying to associate an `acceleration` value with a UIView)

I would add an acceleration property to UIView via a category, like this:

UIView+acceleration.h:

```
@interface UIView ( Acceleration )
@property ( nonatomic ) CGPoint acceleration ;
@end
```

UIView+acceleration.m

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIView ( Acceleration )

const char * kAccelerationKey = "acceleration" ; // should use something with a prefix just in case

-(void)setAcceleration:(CGPoint)acceleration
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, kAccelerationKey, [ NSValue valueWithCGPoint:acceleration ], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC ) ;
}

-(CGPoint)acceleration
{
    return [ objc_setAssociatedObject( self, kAccelerationKey ) CGPointValue ] ;
}

@end
```

Delete `-accelerationForView:` and `-willRemoveSubview:` and use `view.acceleration = <some point>` or `<some point> = view.acceleration`.

Comment: Depending on when the code was written, the original author may not have had that option. Also, a drawback with adding it to `UIView` is that every single view in your app will then have an acceleration, which could be overkill. A better approach might be to create a UIView subclass that keeps track of acceleration. You could then use that as a container for any other view.

Comment: I prefer composition over subclassing. The point here is to explicitly add `acceleration` to all UIView's in the system so you don't have to replace all `UIView`s with a subclass. (It's just plain old `UIView`.) The resource consumption is almost nothing, about equal to the OP's current code. 2 methods (exist once per process), and zero storage except for those views that have had `acceleration` set.